# Do you have to save the Open XML document after working on it?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, office-interop, openxml-sdk

Sorry, here's a stupid question. I've been working on a document using the Open XML SDK and I don't see the changes I've made to it after I dispose off the `SpreadsheetDocument` object.

```
using (var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file, true))
{
    // do stuff to the document
}


// when I exit the program and open the workbook as an end-user
// I don't see any of the changes I made
```

I think I used to see the changes with examples I did before but I can't be so sure.

Do you have to save the document after working on it to see the changes? I don't see such a method to save the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, a little bit of searching revealed to me what I'd forgotten. Apparently, you have to save the XML DOM you just updated.

Since I updated the `WorksheetPart`, and the `WorksheetPart` is of type `OpenXmlPart` and its DOM is represented by the `Worksheet` property of type `Worksheet`, I had to do this:

```
using (var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file, true))
{
    // do stuff to the document

    // finally
    worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
}
```